# How to find the middle value in an array containing strings

Tags: javascript

```
var someValues = ["abc", "def", "ghi" , "jkl", "mno"]
```

How to find the middle value in an array containing strings? Want to extract only the value "ghi". 
Math.floor applies only for numbers.

Not looking for if and else.

Comment: `someValues[Math.floor(someValues.length/2)]`

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: Why don't you use `arr.length / 2` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be what you are looking for.

Just divide the length of your array by two and round it down (`Math.floor()`).

```js
function middle(arr) {
  if (arr.length === 0) return undefined;
  return arr[Math.floor(arr.length / 2)];
}

var someValues = ["abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno"];
console.log(middle(someValues));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use bitshifting by one bit to right, which divides the value by two and returns an integer number for the middle index.

```js
var someValues = ["abc", "def", "ghi" , "jkl", "mno"],
    middle = someValues[someValues.length >> 1];
    
console.log(middle);
```